# While fitting the model with all possible predictors it throws this error TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dataset=pd.read_csv('50_Startups.csv')
x=dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
y=dataset.iloc[:,4].values
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder ,OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
labelencoder_x=LabelEncoder()
x[:,3]=labelencoder_x.fit_transform(x[:,3])

columntransformer = ColumnTransformer([("Country", OneHotEncoder(), [3])], remainder = 'passthrough')
x = columntransformer.fit_transform(x)
x=x[:,1:]
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
xtrain,xtest,ytrain,ytest=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=1/3,random_state=0)
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor=LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
ypred=regressor.predict(xtest)

import statsmodels.api as sm
x=np.append(arr=np.ones((50,1)).astype(float),values=x,axis=1)

xopt=x[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]] 


regressorols=sm.OLS(endog = y,exog = xopt).fit()
regressorols.summary()
```

**and the output is**

> *runcell(0,
>   'C:/Users/patil/Downloads/P14-Machine-Learning-AZ-Template-Folder/Machine
>   Learning A-Z Template Folder/Part 2 - Regression/Section 5 - Multiple
>   Linear Regression/untitled0.py') Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\patil\Downloads\P14-Machine-Learning-AZ-Template-Folder\Machine
>   Learning A-Z Template Folder\Part 2 - Regression\Section 5 - Multiple
>   Linear Regression\untitled0.py", line 36, in 
>       regressorols=sm.OLS(endog = y,exog = xopt).fit()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\patil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py",
>   line 859, in **init**
>       hasconst=hasconst, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\patil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py",
>   line 702, in **init**
>       weights=weights, hasconst=hasconst, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\patil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py",
>   line 190, in **init**
>       super(RegressionModel, self).**init**(endog, exog, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\patil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py",
>   line 236, in **init**
>       super(LikelihoodModel, self).**init**(endog, exog, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\patil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py",
>   line 77, in **init**
>       **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\patil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py",
>   line 100, in _handle_data
>       data = handle_data(endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\patil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\data.py",
>   line 672, in handle_data
>       **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\patil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\data.py",
>   line 87, in **init**
>       self._handle_constant(hasconst)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\patil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\data.py",
>   line 132, in _handle_constant
>       if not np.isfinite(exog_max).all():
>
> TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the
>   inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to

the casting rule ''safe''*

Answer (score 0):

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
x=np.append(arr=np.ones((50,1)).astype(float),values=x,axis=1)
x=x.astype(float)
xopt=x[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]] 


regressorols=sm.OLS(endog = y,exog = xopt).fit()
regressorols.summary()
```

worked

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.